# what's the most elegant way of moving records across collections in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a rather huge collection A.
some of the data gets somewhat obsolete, but still required, and I will want to move it to a "Collection_A_Archive", and keep a record in Redis about what record is in what collection,
what's the most elegant way to achieve this? how do you guys do it?